# Managing multiple rabbitmq clusters

Tags: cluster, user-management, rabbitmq

I have a bunch of Rabbit clusters which I'd like to synchronize users, permissions, and some configuration across. Is there a decent existing solution to this, or do people mostly just write their own software to interact with the REST API to manage syncing.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration management tools such as Ansible, Puppet, and Chef can provide options for configuring RabbitMQ consistently across clusters.